# Keep initialized variables after executing Celery task

Tags: python, celery

I have some code which is like this :

```
model = None

@app.task()
def compute_something():
    global model
    if model is None:
        # Initialize model
    # Use model to perform computation
```

So I want the set-up code (lengthy model initialization) to be executed only once when necessary, and further call to the same task could be reusing these initialized variable.

I know it partly breaks the concept of tasks being strictly atomics. But by default this does not seem to work because (I assume) multiprocessing forks separate processes for each tasks, losing the initialization.

Is there a way to achieve something like this?

RELATED QUESTION:

Another way to look at this, is there a way for a worker to look into the task queue and group tasks to perform them together more efficiently?

Let's say a worker will be much more efficient processing a group of tasks at the same time, than doing them one after the other (GPU job for instance, or here loading a big parameter file into memory).

I was wondering if there was a way for the worker to gather several instances of the same task in the task queue and process them in a batch way instead of one by one.

Answer (score 0):

you may be able to initialise the model at module level:

```
model = initialise_model()

@app.task()
def compute_something():
    # Use model to perform computation
```

however this assumes that the model initialisation does not depend on anything passed to the task and that the model is not modified in any way by the task.

The second question doesn't make much sense. Can you give some context? What do you mean by "group tasks" exactly? Do you want certain tasks to run on a particular host to optimise access to a shared resource? If so then read the celery documentation about routing.

Comment: Yeah I'll probably do this, but 2/3 of the time is used by this model loading and I don't know if I'll need to call this task in advance, so that would be a waste of RAM. For the second part of the question, I edited my question.

Comment: I'm not sure how i understand how a worker is supposed to process a group of tasks "in a batch way". the worker would need an understanding of the request data in order to aggregate it, right? Such a modification would require you to modify the celery worker code...

Comment: Yeah I feared that, but I was wondering if maybe there was a way. For instance I understand that workers can reserve tasks in advance, so grouping the same task reserved instances together would be a plus already.